# How to add react-spring animation component to React lazy loading?

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading, react-spring, react-suspense, react-lazy-load

I try use React lazy and Suspense loading. I have simple login page and animation page for lazy loading. But if I refresh or open this page I cant see animation. But when write `fallback = <p> Loading... </p>`  like this it is work. How to do I do this with animaition?

This is my main page for lazy loading:

```
import { lazy, Suspense } from "react";
import Login_Register from "../Loadingsss/login-register";

const Example = lazy(()=>import ('./Login'));

function Login(){

    return (
        <Suspense fallback={ Login_Register }>
            <Example />
        </Suspense>
    );

}

export default Login;
```

and this animation page:

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import {animated, useSpring} from 'react-spring';

function Login_Register(){

    const [toogle, setToggle] = useState(true);

    const props = useSpring({
        width: toogle===true ?'22rem':'0rem',
        backgroundColor: toogle ? '#ccc' : 'rgb(175, 175, 175)',
        height: '100%',
        borderRadius: '10px'
    });

    setInterval( ()=>{
        setToggle(!toogle);
    },1000 );
    
    return (<div className="loading">
        <div className="row">
            <animated.div style = {props.backgroundColor} className="circle"></animated.div>
            <animated.div style={props} className="rectangle"></animated.div>
        </div>
        <div className="row">
            <animated.div style = {props.backgroundColor} className="circle"></animated.div>
            <animated.div style={props} className="rectangle"></animated.div>
        </div>
        <div className="row">
            <animated.div style = {props.backgroundColor} className="circle"></animated.div>
            <animated.div style={props} className="rectangle"></animated.div>
        </div>
        <div className="row">
            <animated.div style = {props.backgroundColor} className="circle"></animated.div>
            <animated.div style={props} className="rectangle"></animated.div>
        </div>
        <div className="row">
            <animated.div style = {props.backgroundColor} className="circle"></animated.div>
            <animated.div style={props} className="rectangle"></animated.div>
        </div>
        
        
    </div>);
}

export default Login_Register;
```

How can I do this like upwork load animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a React Element into `fallback`, not a Component. Surround `Login_Register` with `<` and `/>` to turn that Component into an Element. like this:

`fallback={ <Login_Register /> }`